# Removing some elements from a linked list in C

Tags: c, list, average

I have to remove from a linked list all the elements that are less than or equal to the "media". I have written this function but it doesn't work on some input.

Code:

```
typedef struct lista {
        int dato;
        struct lista *next;
        }
    node;

......
.....
.....

void filtra_elementi(node ** head, int media)
{
node *prec, *corr;
while(((*head)->dato <= media) &&((*head!=NULL)))
    {
    corr=(*head)->next;
    free(*head);
    *head=corr;

    }
prec=*head; corr=(*head)->next;
while(corr!=NULL)
    {
    if(corr->dato<=media)
      {
      prec->next=corr->next;
      //free(corr);
      corr=prec->next;
      }
     else prec=corr; corr=corr->next;
    }
}
```

Here is the function.
It doesn't work if the list is
0 10 1 11 3 13 4 14 5 15
Can someone explain to me why? Thanks.

Comment: why don't you put your code here.

Comment: Please be specific, what do you mean by it doesn't work, i.e. what is the desired and what is the actual output/result

Comment: You're right but I don't know how to do it. 
The goal is to remove the elements that are less equal to the "media"(one of the parameter). 
But something goes wrong in the second while if I submit the input 0 10 1 11 3 13 4 14 5 15 as original list

Comment: Yes, but *what* "something"?

Comment: `while(((*head)->dato <= media) &&((*head!=NULL)))
    {` change the order. (short-circuis guarantees the order)

Comment: The average is 7 but he removes me also 11,13 and 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 corr=prec->next;
  }
 else prec=corr; corr=corr->next;//corr=corr->next is not in else part and will always be executed.
}
```

what you want is

```
 corr=prec->next;
  }
 else 
 {prec=corr; 
  corr=corr->next;
 }
}
```

Also your while condition is wrong.You should change the order of the checks.Think what will happen if `(*head)` is `null` then accessing `(*head)->dato)` is going to cause runtime error.If you use this

```
while(((*head!=NULL)) && ((*head)->dato <= media))
```

if `(*head)` is `null` `(*head)->dato` won't be accessed.

Comment: corr=corr->next; is not part of else.  Without brackets {  }, else will only use the very next statement.  It is misleading since you have them both on the same line, visually.

Comment: @GiovanniMauro `corr=corr->next` will be executed whether the `if` part is executed or `else` part is executed.because it is not in the else part,its a separate statement which will be executed in every run of the while loop

Comment: I'm a stupid, I don't know why I've forgotten the brackets after the else. Thank you all very very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of the function, a tad simpler, with one loop only

```
void filtra_elementi(node **head, int media)
{
 node *next;
 while(*head != NULL) {
    next = (*head)->next;
    if((*head)->dato <= media) {
        free(*head);
        *head = next;
    } else {
        head = &((*head)->next);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: "Next" is a field of the struct